# Android simple notification

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to make a simple notification in my android app , but it always cracks.
What I'm doing is that I have a button in the `main activity` when clicked it moves the following notification class :
    package com.megasoft.entangle;

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.megasoft.requests.GetRequest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OfferNotification extends Activity {

String notification = "";
String offerer = "";
String description = "";
String request = "";
String amount = "";
String notificationID = "1";
final String link = "Click here to view";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.offer_notification);

    GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest("http://entangle2.apiary.io/notification/1");
    getRequest.addHeader("sessionID" , "testest");
    getRequest.execute("http://entangle2.apiary.io/notification/1");

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getRequest.get());
        description = json.getString("description");
        offerer = json.getString("offerer");
        request = json.getString("request");
        amount = json.getString("Amount");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    notification = offerer + " has offered " + amount + " on your " + request + link;
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setText(notification);
    createNotification();
}

public void createNotification() {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(RESULT_OK)
            .setContentTitle("Entangle:You got a new offer!")
            .setContentText(notification);


    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this , Notification.class);

    TaskStackBuilder sb = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    sb.addParentStack(Notification.class);
    sb.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent pIntent = 
            sb.getPendingIntent(0 , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationMgr = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int ID = Integer.parseInt(notificationID);
    notificationMgr.notify(ID , mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue is with the 'addParentStack' call, Your trying to add the Notification class as parent. It should be your `OfferNotification Activity` which is the parent.

```
  sb.addParentStack(OfferNotification.class);
```

Other issue is the Intent action should be an Activity.

```
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this , YourActivity.class);
```

Next issue is with the `setSmallIcon` , you should pass a valid resource id.

```
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
```

Make all these three changes, Your are out of cracks.

Comment: Thanks I made all these three changes , and no cracks anymore, but still no notifications are created.

Comment: check the device settings,if show notification is enabled for your app

Comment: the notification is enabled , I think it's because I'm on the application

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure when your app "cracks" you're throwing a `RemoteServiceException` and your logcat reads something like:

> Bad notification posted from package: Couldn't create icon:

This happens because you're passing `Activity.RESULT_OK` in `NotificationCompat.Builder.setSmallIcon`. You need to be passing in a `Drawable` resource.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Entangle:You got a new offer!")
            .setContentText(notification);
```

Comment: Thanks , that works , it's not cracking , but no notifications are formed :\